# if statement and scope in javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

**EDIT:** ADDED OBJECT

I'm having an issue with a variable declared within the body of a function that seems to disappear before the variable is returned from the function:

```
var customerData = {
  'Joe': {
    visits: 1
  },
  'Carol': {
    visits: 2
  },
  'Howard': {
    visits: 3,
  },
  'Carrie': {
    visits: 4
  }
};

function greetCustomer(firstName) {
  var greeting = '';

  for(var key in customerData){
    if(key === firstName){
      if(customerData[key]['visits'] === 1){
         greeting = "Welcome back, " + firstName + "! We're glad you liked us the first time!";
        console.log(greeting); // here to illustrate issue
      }
      else if(customerData[key]['visits'] > 1){
        greeting = "Welcome back, " + firstName + "! So glad to see you again!";
        console.log(greeting);
      }
    }
    else{
      greeting = "Welcome! Is this your first time?"
    }
  }

  return greeting;
}
greetCustomer("Joe");
```

And the output:

```
Welcome back, Joe! We're glad you liked us the first time! // here is the correct greeting from the console output
=> 'Welcome! Is this your first time?' // this is what I got
Welcome back, Carol! So glad to see you again! // correct output again
=> 'Welcome! Is this your first time? // base case again.
```

Shouldn't `greeting` be visible throughout the function for accessing its value *and* for assignment as well? I *know* that I can just return the greeting from the branch, but I'm unsure as to what I'm seeing here, but I hope someone can explain. Thanks.

Comment: Your output is not clear! Please explain more! What do you expect?

Comment: You're looping through the data and every iteration writes something to the `greeting` variable. Only the value set in the last iteration is returned.

Comment: The variable is absolutely visible throughout your function. Your error is somewhere else

Comment: Try some debugging. Open your console and add a breakpoint at the start of the `greetCustomer` function. Does your `customerData` have a key `Joe`? Step through your for loop and compare the input Joe to the object.

Comment: what does customerData look like and where is it defined? the issue is most likely stemming from  scoping issues with that instead

Comment: Its seems There is nothing wrong with `greeting` visibility. your outer if doesn't let program routine get into number-of-visits check at all, and it pushes it to else statement. There is no block visibility in js (except for `catch` block), so greeting is sure visible throughout your function.

Comment: I get a down vote because my computer freezes.... nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code iterates over the available keys in the `customerData` object. When it sees a key matching `firstName` it assigns to `greeting` and logs it.

Then it *continues* to iterate over the other keys and if the next key does not match `firstName` (which it probably won't), `greeting` is assigned `"Welcome! Is this your first time?"`. This value is eventually returned from the function. When `firstName` happens to be the last key in `customerData` then your code will work OK, otherwise `greeting` will be reassigned with the default value.

So the basic problem is that your code continues processing after it has found and processed the target value, and that it reassigns the `greetings` string. There is no issue with scope or visibility of the `greeting` variable - it is a local variable to function `greetCustomer`.

One way to fix this is to return immediately after assigning the greeting (as you already noted). Another way is to use `break` to exit the for loop. Then `greeting` will be returned at the end of the function.

```
function greetCustomer(firstName) {
  var greeting = '';

  for(var key in customerData){
    if(key === firstName){
      if(customerData[key]['visits'] === 1){
         greeting = "Welcome back, " + firstName + "! We're glad you liked us the first time!";
        console.log(greeting); // here to illustrate issue
      }
      else if(customerData[key]['visits'] > 1){
        greeting = "Welcome back, " + firstName + "! So glad to see you again!";
        console.log(greeting);
      }
      break;    // customer name found and appropriate greeting set, exit loop
    }
    else{
      greeting = "Welcome! Is this your first time?"
    }
  }

  return greeting;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For success conditions immediately return greeting instead of assigning it to `greeting` variable. But for the condition where `firstname` is not one of keys in `customerData`, just set `greeting` to `"Welcome! Is this your first time?"` & let the iteration continue to look for `firstname.

Change your code to this [TESTED]:

```
function greetCustomer(firstName) {
var greeting = '';

for(var key in customerData){
  if(key === firstName){
    if(customerData[key]['visits'] === 1){
      return("Welcome back, " + firstName + "! We're glad you liked us the first time!");
      console.log(greeting); // here to illustrate issue
    }
    else if(customerData[key]['visits'] > 1){
      return("Welcome back, " + firstName + "! So glad to see you again!");
     }
   }
   else{
    greeting = "Welcome! Is this your first time?";
  }
}
return greeting;
}
console.log(greetCustomer("Joe"));
```